# .htaccess pagination on subdomain not working [PHP]

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Let me make it clear, I'm having as base this url `domain.com/feedbacks.php?id=exampleuser&page=1`

Now using .htaccess I want to rewrite it into this :

`exampleuser.domain.com/?page=1`

I successfully obtained exampleuser.domain.com but sadly adding & using as pagination the parameter `?page=` within my subdomain is not working.

How can I make the the PHP ?page= parameter work using .htaccess?

Or is it any other way that I can simply rewrite `domain.com/feedbacks.php?id=exampleuser&page=1` to `exampleuser.domain.com/?page=1`?

Comment: Please give a real example of a requested URL. What you posted above (`https://user-feed.domain.com/?id=user&page=1 `) appears to be something between the requested URL and what it should get rewritten to.

Comment: And I really wonder about that strange pattern in your first rule: `^([aA-zZ])$` ... That captures exactly one character, namely a "a" or a "Z". I doubt that is, what you want ...

Comment: The requested url is : `domain.com/feed.php?id=user&page=1`

Comment: And I want to rewrite it as `subdomain.domain.com/?id=user&page=1 `

Comment: Presumably it must be the other way round? If the requested URL is `/feed.php?id=user&page=1` then there's nothing to do - you are already at the endpoint. You need to explain in natural language what you are trying to do and what you think those directives doing. They obviously aren't doing quite what you are expecting, otherwise you would have added the `QSA` flag to the 2nd rule. The 1st rule doesn't really make sense given the 2nd rule?

Comment: Ok its a total misunderstanding as I can see, let me explain again.

Comment: I'm trying to get this : `domain.com/?id=exampleuser&page=1` to this        `exampleuser.domain.com/?page=1`

Comment: Please edit your question, there is an "edit" button for that. Add a clear and simple example: what URL do you type into the browser? Probably the one with the subdomain? What is the internal resource that should get called? How do you think your rules implement that?

Comment: Reason for the last comment: what you added in comments here is even more confusing than your question. You need to clear that up.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope its clear now

Comment: But unfortunately you now threw out your rule implementation, yet you refer to it mentioning that some specific detail does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is still unclear after the edit, you now dropped important information. So I make give a try here to point out the basics. You probably have to adapt it to your specific needs which are not really clear from your description:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /feedbacks.php?id=%1 [QSA,END]
```

This obviously assumes that requests to the http host ".example.com" are received and processed at all by your http server. For that you need to setup the correct (wildcard) DNS records *and* you need to use a default virtual host to catch requests to arbitrary requested host names.

The given rule set can be implemented in the central http server's host configuration for that default host. Or, if you do not have access to that you can instead use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"), *if* you enabled that feature before hand (see the documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive for that).

I kept this as simple as possible to prevent complexity. You need to understand how this works. And I really recommend that you start taking a look into the documentation of the tool you are using, here the http server's rewriting module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

The rule assumes that the "page=" query parameter is correctly set by the requesting site. If not then it is missing, so your application logic has to handle that case (it will probably return the first page then).

This does _not handle requests to the host "example.com" (you did not specify how). And it also only implements an internal rewrite for *incoming* requests. You have to take care elsewhere that references (link) you send out already use the hostname that specifies the user id.